# Java: Grabbing a key event without a KeyListener or using any other custom classes

Tags: java, class, compression, keyevent

This is a bit of an odd question, but it is worth an ask: Is there any way to generically grab a key event in Java without the use of a key listener, key bindings, key dispatcher, etc? The goal here is to not utilize any overloaded classes (ex. new KeyListener() { ... }).

I am trying to see how small I can make a simple game, and using overloaded classes takes up quite a bit of space relative to the normal code because they require an entire class file of their own when they are packaged into a jar.

Comment: If you really want to avoid adding a KeyListener, I suppose you could just override the `processKeyEvent(KeyEvent)` method of the component that you are targeting.

Comment: @JoshM : That solution seems to work very nicely as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no way.
2. You can use anonymous (or named) inner classes if you want to avoid separate source files. In fact, anonymous inner classes are extremely common to use for simple listeners or adapters.  You can also implement KeyListener in your main logic class, although that's a bit unusual, but it depends on your situation.

   ```
   void example () {

       JComponent component = ...;

       component.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
           @Override public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
               // do stuff
           }
       });

   }
   ```

   See [Anonymous Class Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).
3. JARs are compressed, you're talking on the order of hundreds of bytes here.

Comment: Yea, I know it is seriously knit-picking, but I was thinking about trying my luck at Java4k eventually and every byte counts there. Anonymous inner classes were what I was talking about when I said overloaded classes (I couldn't remember the name of what they were called, sorry). When I use those, they generate another class file inside the jar which is on the order of a few hundred bytes. I took your advice on just having the main class implement the KeyListener interface, and that actually made it so the extra class file wasn't generated (which was what I was going for). Thanks!

Comment: If Java4k let's you use ProGuard you can shave a few bytes off that way too. Also, the `-g:none` option to `javac` will leave out debug info.